# How to make a table head sticky but with overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table, sticky

I am trying to make the  of a table sticky to top of page as you scroll, however the table width should be constrained by its parent and allow to scroll in the x direction.

However as soon as the overflow-x is added, the stickyness doesn't work, and if there's no overflow, then the head sticks, but the table content breaks the bounds of its parent container.

Example Pen
https://codepen.io/JamesBlack91/pen/KKRJdQK

```
div {
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <th>Column 5</th>
        <th>Column 6</th>
        <th>Column 7</th>
        <th>Column 8</th>
        <th>Column 9</th>
        <th>Column 10</th>
        <th>Column 11</th>
        <th>Column 12</th>
        <th>Column 13</th>
        <th>Column 14</th>
        <th>Column 15</th>
        <th>Column 16</th>
        <th>Column 17</th>
        <th>Column 18</th>
        <th>Column 19</th>
        <th>Column 20</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you scroll, the head isn't sticky, but if you comment out the overflow on the div, the head is sticky but the columns overflow the 300px max.

I have read all about thead (previously) not supporting sticky, I've also tried on the < th > to no result. I've tried putting overflow on the table/thead/tbody instead of the ancestor div, but nothing seems to work.

I really want to avoid using javascript and I'm sure there's a simple css solution I just don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.lock-header {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.lock-header thead th {}

.lock-header>table {}

.lock-header tfoot td {}

.lock-header {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
}

.lock-header thead>tr:first-child>th {
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.lock-header>table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.lock-header tfoot td {
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
  z-index: 99;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="lock-header">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <th>Column 5</th>
        <th>Column 6</th>
        <th>Column 7</th>
        <th>Column 8</th>
        <th>Column 9</th>
        <th>Column 10</th>
        <th>Column 11</th>
        <th>Column 12</th>
        <th>Column 13</th>
        <th>Column 14</th>
        <th>Column 15</th>
        <th>Column 16</th>
        <th>Column 17</th>
        <th>Column 18</th>
        <th>Column 19</th>
        <th>Column 20</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some fake row</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

is this what you want ?
I tried it on codepen and it works

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!
It seems the trick was to add the max-height to the wrapping div, in my case I need it full screen so just changed to 100vh and it's perfect, thank you!

Comment: 100vh feels a bit bad since it does not allow the table to grow longer than the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 4):

This is elegant AND it works:

```
<style>
 
.lock-header { 
  overflow-y: auto; 
  max-height: 500px;
}  
.lock-header thead { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
}

</style>

<div class="lock-header">
    <table>
        <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Column head</th>
             </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>Detail row 1</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>Detail row 2</th>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This can't be done with just CSS. The sticky position requires the initial overflow value on parent containers, you will have to use JS to stick the header row.